# visual scrollbar plugin eclipse

Tags: plugins, eclipse, text-editors

I'm looking for visual scroll bar for eclipse, something like [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) 
Does anyone knows one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Following Might be the options which you looking for

1) [Eclipse Minimap View](https://github.com/apauzies/eclipse-minimap-view)

From Project page image :

[image]

It Works for :

```
Display a preview of the editor content in the minimap
Highlight the viewable part of the editor in the minimap
Scroll/click/drag in the minimap -> scroll the editor
Scroll/click in the editor -> scroll in the minimap
Use the editor colors (syntax, background, selection) in the minimap
```

2)[Overview Plugin](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.se/2013/02/overview-plugin-for-eclipse.html)

From Website page :

[image]

Both does the tasks fine Similar to rocksroll,hope it helps

Comment: I know this is not your question but if you use emacs, you do not have to worry about these kinds of things. Also your productivity will increase dramatically after you pass the initial learning curve. Google Steve Yegge and emacs, he has written several articles. They are humorous as well.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus agreed :)